# T-SQL recursive query that sorts by parent level only

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

I am trying to achieve the following requirement:

**I have a hierarchy of products with their spare parts. Those spare parts can have other parts in a graph that can potentially have several layers of depth.**

My goal is to write a T-SQL query that allows me to order by any column of the table (in the example Product, Price or EndOfWarrantyDate) but keeping the hierarchy. In other words, **I want to order only the parent items, without worrying about the children that should come into play ONLY to follow their parents**.

In the example below, if you notice, the green rows are sorted by "EndOfWarrantyDate", but I still want to show the children and sub-children next to their parent (I don't care about ordering the children, as long as the hierarchy is respected).

[image: Table Example]

*NOTE: the Id in the table above is just there to better identify the hierarchy, in the db I have a normal identity column as Id.*

And, if possible, I would like to do that in a single SQL query, without having to collect the parent items first, order them and then get the related children and subchildren.

My CTE at the moment looks like this, but I have no idea how to achieve the sorting. Tried with a PARTITION, but don't know how to apply it properly to solve my issue.

```
WITH
  cteProducts (Id, Product, ParentProductId, Price, EndOfWarrantyDate, Depth, RootId)
  AS
  (
-->>>>>>>>>>Root>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
    SELECT Id, Product, ParentProductId, Price, EndOfWarrantyDate, 0 as Depth, Id as RootId
    FROM Products
    WHERE ParentProductId IS NULL
-->>>>>>>>>>Root>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
    UNION ALL
-->>>>>>>>>>Children>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>    
    SELECT e.Id, e.Product, e.ParentProductId, e.Price, e.EndOfWarrantyDate, r.Depth + 1, r.RootId
    FROM Products e
      INNER JOIN cteProducts r
        ON e.ParentProductId = r.Id
-->>>>>>>>>>Children>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
  )
SELECT
  Id, Product, ParentProductId, Price, EndOfWarrantyDate, Depth, RootId
FROM cteProducts
--ORDER BY RootId, EndOfWarrantyDate
```

Any help is very appreciated, thank you!

Comment: You can add `Row_Number()` in the _anchor_ of your recursive CTE with `order by case when @SortColumn = 'Product' then Product when ... end`. Note that all columns need to be converted to a compatible type, e.g. the warranty date will need to be a sortable string: YYYYMMDD. In the _recursive_ part of the CTE just propagate the value to the children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preserve the parent `EndOfWarrantyDate` as part of your recursive CTE. This way you can sort on it in the end.

**Sample data**

```
declare @Products table
(
    Id nvarchar(10),
    Product nvarchar(20),
    ParentProductId nvarchar(10),
    Price int,
    EndOfWarrantyDate date
);

insert into @Products (Id, Product, ParentProductId, Price, EndOfWarrantyDate) values
('1',       'Vacuum',           null,   130,    '2013-04-02'),
('1.1',     'Power Unit',       '1',    200,    '2024-01-01'),
('1.1.1',   'Unit part',        '1.1',  100,    '2024-01-01'),
('1.2',     'Filter',           '1',    10,     '2022-07-15'),
('2',       'Laptop',           null,   600,    '2023-06-01'),
('2.1',     'Hard Disk',        '2',    200,    '2024-03-01'),
('3',       'Washing Machine',  null,   1000,   '2023-12-01');
```

**Solution**

```
WITH
  cteProducts (Id, Product, ParentProductId, Price, EndOfWarrantyDate, Depth, RootId, ParentDate)
  AS
  (
-->>>>>>>>>>Root>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
    SELECT Id, Product, ParentProductId, Price, EndOfWarrantyDate, 0 as 'Depth', Id as 'RootId'
            ,EndOfWarrantyDate as 'ParentDate' -- new field
    FROM @Products
    WHERE ParentProductId IS NULL
-->>>>>>>>>>Root>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
    UNION ALL
-->>>>>>>>>>Children>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>    
    SELECT e.Id, e.Product, e.ParentProductId, e.Price, e.EndOfWarrantyDate, r.Depth + 1, r.RootId
            ,r.ParentDate -- new field
    FROM @Products e
      INNER JOIN cteProducts r
        ON e.ParentProductId = r.Id
-->>>>>>>>>>Children>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
  )
SELECT ParentDate,
  Id, Product, ParentProductId, Price, EndOfWarrantyDate, Depth, RootId
FROM cteProducts
order by ParentDate, Id; -- new field as first sort field
```

**Result**

```
ParentDate Id         Product              ParentProductId Price       EndOfWarrantyDate Depth       RootId
---------- ---------- -------------------- --------------- ----------- ----------------- ----------- ----------
2013-04-02 1          Vacuum               NULL            130         2013-04-02        0           1
2013-04-02 1.1        Power Unit           1               200         2024-01-01        1           1
2013-04-02 1.1.1      Unit part            1.1             100         2024-01-01        2           1
2013-04-02 1.2        Filter               1               10          2022-07-15        1           1
2023-06-01 2          Laptop               NULL            600         2023-06-01        0           2
2023-06-01 2.1        Hard Disk            2               200         2024-03-01        1           2
2023-12-01 3          Washing Machine      NULL            1000        2023-12-01        0           3
```

Comment: This doesn't quite cover the "order by any column" part of the problem without adding all of the interesting columns to the CTE as `Parent<Something>` and changing the `order by` clause to a `case` expression the selects the appropriate `Parent<Something>` column.

Comment: Thanks Sander, a slight modification of your solution seems to work as intended. 
Basically my Id column is actually just an integer Id, so I have created a calculated column to achieve that hierarchy Id you see in my table.

And to answer @HABO the solution works for any column as I'm going to call this through Dapper in C# and I can parameterize the SortingColumn (I don't care about the name of the computed field, it can be a fixed 'SortingField' column)